# libCurl. Cancel request while proceed

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

UPDATED: Problem was not in libcurl. The right way to cancel request if to return from callback non-zero value. I used curl_progress_callback function, and everything works fine.

Comment: The code as shown is fine. The problem is elsewhere. Show all the code.

Comment: @n.m. but when I write that ProgressShow always return 0 everything works without errors!

Comment: It is not possible to diagnose a problem with a gun if all you have is a picture of the trigger.

Comment: @n.m. I think I have copied all the code.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the crash. Perhaps you should run the program under the debugger and analyse the traceback. Also, the program as posted lacks headers and `main`, and has compilation errors (values returned from a `void` function); I had to fix all that to test it. It should not be that hard to post the program that crashes verbatim.

Comment: That's a Q&A site here with a huge archive. I don't think it is wise to delete answered questions, requiring other people to browse through the version history to be able to see the question at a later stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to understand is that CURL is a C library. In general, you cannot pass pointers to C++ objects or functions because C does not know anything about C++'s classes and calling convention.

For example, this line is incorrect:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errorBuffer);
```

CURL setopt `CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER` expects that the third parameter is a pointer to a C-style string (C-style `char` array) having space for `CURL_ERROR_SIZE` chars. You are instead passing a pointer to a `std::string` object. As CURL, being written in C, does not know what a `std::string` is, it simply overwrites the byte representation having `sizeof (std::string)` bytes with the error data because it thinks that the pointer is to a C-style `char` array.

Use this instead:

```
char errorBuffer[CURL_ERROR_SIZE + 1]; errorBuffer[CURL_ERROR_SIZE] = '\0';
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, errorBuffer);
```

`errorBuffer` is only filled with a valid string if `curl_easy_perform()` returns an error code.

Also, `Uploader::WriteResponce` is a C++ function. With this line:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteResponce);
```

CURL expects the third parameter to be a pointer-to-C function. Here, you are passing a pointer-to-C++ function. You need to wrap the call to `WriteResponce` in an `extern "C"` function that calls the C++ function:

```
extern "C" size_t call_uploader_writeresponce(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *user_data) {
    return Uploader::WriteResponce(ptr, size, nmemb, static_cast<std::string *>(user_data));
}


// ...
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &call_uploader_writeresponce);
```

The "write function" needs to return `size_t`, not `int`; `Uploader::WriteResponce` needs to return `size_t`.

Comment: But all that works fine. As I write above program crashes only when ProgressShow returns non-zero. I did what you say - the same thing

Comment: @Alecs: It might work, but it definitely is not going to work all the time because it is invoking undefined behavior. Please update your question with the new code, the version that contains fixes for the issues that I mentioned.

Comment: I have tried without class at all, and still the same thing. Question updated

Comment: @Alecs: `char errorBuffer[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];` needs to be `char errorBuffer[CURL_ERROR_SIZE + 1];` Also, try explicitly casting `body.length()` to `curl_off_t` when setting the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE` option: `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE, static_cast<curl_off_t>(body.length()));`

Comment: @Alecs: Where does the debugger say that the segfault occurs?

Comment: Oh, I find out what was wrong! It is in that code that I didnt show, I was sure with it, I had error with string, in which response was hold. I didnt think that when request is aborted this string would be uninitialised, i thought that it will be NULL. Thanks for your help a lot!