# C++ and cUrl : how to get SSL error codes

Tags: c++, ssl, curl, error-handling

I am establishing a connection to a secured server over SSL.
Everything works fine, my CAcertificate is well used through

```
retCode=curl_easy_setopt(handleCurl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, sSSLCertificate);
retCode=curl_easy_setopt(handleCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
```

I'm stuck when i try to manage curl errors. Basically i want to be able to be notified when a problem happens with the SSL (wrong cacert.pem, server identity not verified etc).

Nothing happens when CURLOPT_CAINFO is given an empty CAcert, retCode is OK.

I tried to get info after the request with that :

```
res = curl_easy_getinfo(m_pHandleCurl, CURLINFO_SSL_VERIFYRESULT, &lSSLVerifyResult);
```

But it always tells me that everithing is fine.

What am i missing ?

Comment: You can find good hints on error handling in libCURL here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400127/libcurl-cancel-request-while-proceed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to your connection setup code:

```
// Make sure this is NOT a stack variable! The buffer
// must be available through whole live of the connection
char buffer[CURL_ERROR_SIZE+1] = {};

retCode=curl_easy_setopt(handleCurl, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, buffer);
```

then when your connection has ended, check what's in the buffer - you should be able to see some hints regarding SSL state, too. It will be empty if no error occurred.

If you want actual code, numeric `CURLcode` is always returned by `curl_easy_perform` for easy handles.

If you use multi handles, use `curl_multi_info_read` instead. Here is example:

```
int u = 0;
if (CURLM_OK == curl_multi_perform(multi_, &u))
{
  int q = 0;
  CURLMsg *msg = NULL;
  while ((msg = curl_multi_info_read(multi_, &q)) != NULL)
  {
    if (msg->msg == CURLMSG_DONE)
    {
      CURL* easy = msg->easy_handle;
      CURLcode code = msg->data.result;
      // . . .
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, i just tried that and got some result : "error setting certificate verify locations:..." but i'd rather have an err number or something to switch onto, like that for example : http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html

Comment: whereas i use curl_multi_perform in my app and it's error codes are not as usefull as curl_easy_perform's.

Comment: In this case use field "result" of CURLMsg returned by http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_info_read.html