# c++ libcurl SSL connect error

Tags: c++, windows, curl, ssl, libcurl

I try to connect to a server with a selfsigned SSL certificate. 
I already tried those skip certificate checks, it does work on the PC I compile it, but it does not work on an external computer. It gives me the 'SSL CONENCT ERROR' on an external Windows computer.

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
```

PS: How to read the error buffer?

CURLE_SSL_CONNECT_ERROR (35)

A problem occurred somewhere in the SSL/TLS handshake. You really want the error buffer and read the message there as it pinpoints the problem slightly more. Could be certificates (file formats, paths, permissions), passwords, and others.

Comment: How do you know that the failure is because of certificate verification error? Are you sure it is not a firewall issue?

Comment: @jxh Documentation suggests so: CURLE_SSL_CONNECT_ERROR (35)

A problem occurred somewhere in the SSL/TLS handshake. You really want the error buffer and read the message there as it pinpoints the problem slightly more. Could be certificates (file formats, paths, permissions), passwords, and others.

Comment: Did you check the "and others" part?

Comment: @jxh How do I suppose to do that? It's like finding a needle in a haystack.

Comment: First, you try to rule out certificate verification error. For example, you can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to inspect the traffic and see what the handshake messages are.

Comment: @jxh It works fine in the browsers after accepting the certificate (firefox, chrome, etc.)

Comment: That doesn't mean your application works the same as the browsers. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912772/c-and-curl-how-to-get-ssl-error-codes to get the error strings.

Comment: @jxh the "SSL connect error" only shows ip when using the domainname, it does seem to work if I use the IP address instead.

Comment: Your choices are: (1) bad network, (2) bad SSL library, (3) bad SSL configuration, (4) bad code. You have to figure out which one it is. Once you have, then if it is bad code, and you can't figure out why, post the code here and ask. If it is one of the others, you probably need to ask on a different site, like [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) or [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).